# stop and progress bar overlapped in jplayer

Tags: css, jplayer

I use jplayer but button stop and progress bar overlapped

Please See image below

i have added code in css but no luck:

```
div.jp-jplayer div.jp-type-playlist div.jp-progress{
    right:300px
}
```

I want to change the css so that the player interface doesn't overlap.

My public link: https://procfu.com/testlab/audio/2516578504

[image]
Please help

My javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
    }, [
        {
        title: "Name 1",
         mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3",
            },
            {
                title:"Name 2",
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3",
            },
            {
                title:"Nam 3",
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3",
            }
    ], {

        play:function(a){
            console.log(a.jPlayer.status.media.poster);   
        },
        swfPath: "../../dist/jplayer",
        supplied: "oga, mp3",
        wmode: "window"
    });
});
```